# How to add react routing with dynamically imported components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm learning React Router at the moment and would like to know if it's possible to import react component and routing though the API. I want to import the component each page.

I have this code:

```
import React, { lazy, useEffect, useState, Suspense} from 'react';
import shortid from 'shortid';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useHistory,
  useLocation,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
```

It is component import function.

```
const importView = subreddit =>
  lazy(() =>
    import(`.${subreddit}`).catch(() => import(`./Component/ComponentNotFound/ComponentNotFound`))
  );
  

  const searchSubreddit = async query =>
  fetch('api/header.json').then(_ => _.json());


export default function App({ subredditsToShow }) {
  const [views, setViews] = useState([]);
  const extractDataFromSearchResult = response =>
    response.data.children.map(({ data }) => data);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadViews() {
      const subredditsToShow = await searchSubreddit('react hooks').then(
        extractDataFromSearchResult
      );

      const componentPromises = subredditsToShow.map(async data => {
        const View = await importView(data.subreddit);
        return <View key={shortid.generate()} {...data} />;

      });

      Promise.all(componentPromises).then(setViews);
    }
    
    loadViews();
  }, [subredditsToShow]);

  const Loading = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div style={{ height: "100vh", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", margin: "0 auto" }} >
          <img style={{ maxHeight: "600px", maxWidth: "800px" }} src="assets/icon/Loader.gif" />
        </div>
      </>
    );

  }
```

```
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" subredditsToShow={views}>
      <Route exact path="/about" subredditsToShow={views}>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

What i am using it is good way or not? Please give your good feedback